# call to ffi_call fails even though arguments look right

Tags: c, c++11, ffi

Consider [this gist](https://gist.github.com/jjpe/96f33585d8986fceb0e5#file-dynlibtest-cc-L96). I have checked and double checked this piece of code for defects and can't find any apparent flaws in the code. It also compiles fine when I use `g++ -g -std=c++11 -Wall dynlibtest.cc -ldl -lffi -lstdc++ -odynlibtest && ./dynlibtest` (the `-ldl` and `-lffi` switches are for the dynamic loading and FFI libraries, respectively).

However, when the highlighted line (l.96) executes it segfaults.

I have also tried pulling it through gdb, and after installing the libc debugging symbols it spits this message out when the `./dynlibtest` bin segfaults:

> > (gdb) next
> >
> > Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
> >     __memcpy_sse2_unaligned () at ../sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch/memcpy-sse2-unaligned.S:157
> >     157     ../sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch/memcpy-sse2-unaligned.S: No such file or directory.

Who can help me understand why this segfaults? Is it a bug of some kind or am I using one of the API's wrong?

For reference: the first part of the code calls `gettimeofday` directly to show that the code can indeed find it, and that even the args are correct when it is called directly.

EDIT: I have added the gdb output when the code segfaults with the output of `bt` also attached:

> $ gdb ./dynlibtest
>   GNU gdb (Ubuntu 7.7.1-0ubuntu5~14.04.2) 7.7.1
>   Copyright (C) 2014 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
>   License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later 
> http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html
>   This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
>   There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type "show copying"
>   and "show warranty" for details.
>   This GDB was configured as "x86_64-linux-gnu".
>   Type "show configuration" for configuration details.
>   For bug reporting instructions, please see:
>   http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/.
>   Find the GDB manual and other documentation resources online at:
>   http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/documentation/.
>   For help, type "help".
>   Type "apropos word" to search for commands related to "word"...
>   Reading symbols from ./dynlibtest...done.
>   (gdb) break 96
>   Breakpoint 1 at 0x401032: file dynlibtest.cc, line 96.
>   (gdb) run
>   Starting program: /home/j/dev/elisp-ffi/dynlibtest 
>   Test started...
>   Got main program handle
>   pre-alloc: tv.tv_sec = 140737340592552
>   Sleeping for 1 second
>   post-alloc: tv.tv_sec = 1432058412
>   Sleeping for 1 second
>   Fn ptr call: tv.tv_sec = 1432058413
>   FFI CIF preparation is OK
>   Sleeping for 1 second
>   Breakpoint 1, main () at dynlibtest.cc:96
>   96          ffi_call(&cif, FFI_FN(gettimeofday), &result, args);
>   (gdb) next
>   Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
>   __memcpy_sse2_unaligned () at ../sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch/memcpy-sse2-unaligned.S:157
>   157     ../sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch/memcpy-sse2-unaligned.S: No such file or directory.
>   (gdb) bt
>   #0  __memcpy_sse2_unaligned () at ../sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch/memcpy-sse2-unaligned.S:157
>   #1  0x00007ffff79d34c2 in memcpy (__len=8, __src=0x0, __dest=0x7fffffffda48) at /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/string3.h:51
>   #2  ffi_call (cif=0x7fffffffdca0, fn=0x400ab0 , rvalue=0x7fffffffdc40, avalue=0x7fffffffdc00) at ../src/x86/ffi64.c:504
>   #3  0x000000000040104e in main () at dynlibtest.cc:96
>   (gdb)

Comment: When the debugger halts, issue a `bt` command to show a stack trace of where the program was when the signal occurred. That might help shed some more light on the issue.

Comment: I've added the info you requested.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the library you're using, but the stack trace shows that it's trying to memcpy from a null pointer. You could look at the libffi code for more details, as it even gives you the line number in their code where it occurs (`ffi64.c:504`). My guess would be a problem in how you're passing the `gettimeofday()` arguments to the `ffi_call()` function.